Nuget package bug 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=8.0.0.0'
I have System.IO.Port nuget package installed in 2 projects in same solution. The version of both is 8.0.0.0. One works correctly, and the other one throws error in runtime, that it can't find it. Copying it to Debug folder, deleting bin folder, Clean and Rebuilding solution does not help. I tried clearing nuget's cache, but the error persists. I also tried deleting the folder C:\Users\Maria.nuget\packages\system.io.ports, deleting the dll from my debug folder and reinstalling the package, but the error persists. There's a more detailed explanation of the issue in this question Updating nuget package but in runtime still uses the old code. It seems like a bug in nuget package manager.
The error is :
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
The problem csproj:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Resources.Extensions" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Both projects communicate with different devices on the serial port, but I've tested the first project before adding the second, and I can't test it again now if it's still working.
The working csproj:
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider></SccProvider>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.1.35" />
    <PackageReference Include="DapperLinqProfilerCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Unity" Version="5.11.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Unity.Container" Version="5.11.11" />
  </ItemGroup>


What exactly does the error message say? Can we see anything relevant from the csproj, in particular the target-framework and the relevant package-references? Do both projects use types from the relevant package? Anything exotic here, like specific OS targets?

Edited the question

What happens if you run msbuild YourProject.csproj /t:Restore?

Please add a complete csproj file. And can you find System.IO.Ports.dll in the output folder after building the project?

"the csproj" - are both projects identical in this regard?

I have added the relevant parts of the other one too

... the working csproj is a library, how can it work alone?

There are other projects in the solution, these two communicate on the serial port. I copied the .dll in the output folder, when I was working on the first project, that uses serial ports, because it wasn't copied automatically.

Will the error disappear if you create a new project targets to net8.0-windows under this solution and add a reference to the package System.IO.Ports ? This problem is similar to this ticket.

I have another project (net8.0-windows), which has a dependency on the problematic project and the error occurs when a class in this project instantiates the class in the other project that has the SerialPort as a property. If I put
var port = new SerialPort("COM8", 115200); port.Open(); port.Close(); before the class instantiation it does not throw the error anymore... This is seriously very strange

It seems that this issue is specific to the code of  problematic project. Could you share a  Minimal, Reproducible Example?

I can't reproduce it in a new solution. I should have added that the solution was originally written in .net Framework 4.8, and I upgraded it to .net 8. Maybe this is part of the reasons for this strange behavior. If no one else is experiencing such problem, maybe we should give up figuring it out. I got it working, even though with a very stupid workaround, so I'm focusing on other assignments. When I eventually figure it out, I'll post it here. Thanks for the efforts.

Okay, if you find the root case of this issue, feel free to let us know the results.;)
